# To which PPA does a package belong to?

Tags: package-management, ppa

Is there a command which returns the ppa which was used to install a certain package? Some command that searches a package in the ppa's.

I know that I could find this info out by looking into synaptic manager, and analysing the package info.

But I would like a command for that.

I use 12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
apt-cache policy <package-name>
```

[image]

Comment: thx. exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I normally use the following command.

```
apt-cache policy <package-name>
```

For example if I want to know the ppa info for winusb I run the following.

```
apt-cache policy winusb
```

[image]

**Resources:**

[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/106794/how-to-tell-from-what-ubuntu-or-debian-repository-a-package-comes)

Answer (score 3):

The two commands I use to get info about a package are

First

`apt-cache policy <package name>`

Second

`apt-cache show <package name>`

The second command is more detailed and I use it a lot.